# 8 bit Ripple carry adder Port mappinng in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I wrote the code for 8 bit adder by usign 4 bit carry look ahead adder. i instantiated the 4 bit caryy look ahed adder using port map. but i think i am wrong for port mapping . plese any one can hel me , how can i correct the port mapping ..

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity adder_4_bit is
Port ( a,b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

       s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       cout: out  STD_LOGIC);
end adder_4_bit;

architecture Behavioral of adder_4_bit is
signal g, p, c, b1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);

begin
g <= a and b;
p <= a xor b;

s(0) <= p(0) ;
c(0) <= g(0) or p(0) ;

s(1) <= p(1) xor c(0);
c(1) <= g(1) or (p(1) and g(0)) or (p(1) and p(0));

s(2) <= p(2) xor c(1);
c(2) <= g(2) or (p(2) and g(1)) or (p(2) and p(1) and g(0)) or (p(2) and p(1) and p(0));

s(3) <= p(3) xor c(2);
c(3) <= g(3) or (p(3) and g(2)) or (p(3) and p(2) and g(1)) or (p(3) and p(2) and p(1) and g(0)) or (p(3) and p(2) and p(1) and p(0));

cout <= c(3);

 end Behavioral;








 library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

 --********************************************************--
entity Adder_8_bit is 
        Port ( 
                 a,b : in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);          
                    s : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
                 cout: out  STD_LOGIC
              );
end Adder_8_bit;k
---******************---
architecture Behavioral of Adder_8_bit is

component  adder_4_bit is
     Port (
             A,B :  in   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
                 S:   out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
             cout: out  STD_LOGIC
             );
end component;
----
signal a1 ,b1 :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); 
signal SUM    :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); 

begin 

four_bit_adder1:  adder_4_bit port map ( a1(3 downto 0) ,b1(3 downto 0) , SUM (3 downto 0) , cout) ; 
four_bit_adder2:  adder_4_bit port map ( a1(7 downto 4) ,b1(7 downto 4) , SUM (7 downto 4) , cout ) ; 

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please describe the desired behavior as well as the specific problem you're having.  Then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: The best help I can give is to suggest writing a testbench for it and getting it to work properly in simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You connect the signal `cout` to two drivers:

```
four_bit_adder1:  adder_4_bit port map ( a1(3 downto 0) ,b1(3 downto 0) , SUM (3 downto 0) , cout);
four_bit_adder2:  adder_4_bit port map ( a1(7 downto 4) ,b1(7 downto 4) , SUM (7 downto 4) , cout );
```

This is wrong, as the toplevel `cout` should have only 1 source, in this case the `four_bit_adder2`.

Your 4 bits adder also requires a carry in, otherwise it is impossible to chain two of them to form a 8 bits adder. The first adder's carry in is '0', the second adder's carry in is the first adder's carry out.

Comment: thank you @Jonathan Drolet , Can you please edit this code . ? Please correct it ..........

Comment: It is not my place to correct your code, especially when you do not provide a complete testbench showing the issue at hand. There are plenty of free resources on carry-lookahead adders on the internet. A quick google search gave me that one: http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~fayez/courses/ceng465/lab_465/project1/adders.pdf It even has detailed equations for a 4-bits carry lookahead adder including the carry in.